# Recursion: Reason for outputting specified text?

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion

I have a simple c++ recursion question. Before I ask my question I think it is best to show the code that I have.

```
void message(int times)
{
  if (times > 0)
  {
    cout << "This is a recursive function" << endl;
    message(times - 1);
  }
  cout << "message returning with " << times << " in times << endl;
}
```

Let the integer variable times be set to 5.
Here is the output for the function

```
This is a recursive function
This is a recursive function
This is a recursive function
This is a recursive function
This is a recursive function
Message called with 0 in times
Message called with 1 in times
Message called with 2 in times
Message called with 3 in times
Message called with 4 in times
Message called with 5 in times
```

I understand why the statement "This is a recursive function" is outputted but I don't understand why the statement "Message called with 0-5 in times" would be outputted? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you would expect different output?

Comment: Stepping through the code in your debugger will show you exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a small portion of your code:

```
    message(times - 1);
}
cout << "message returning with " << times << " in times << endl;
```

What do you think will happen after this function call to message() returns? You do know that when you call a function, once the function call returns the caller resumes executing with the next statement, right?

That's exactly what happens here. So when, for example this code is invoked passing `5` for the value of `times`, that's the message you eventually see.

I'm sure that whatever compiler you're using, you should also have a companion debugger tool that lets you step through your program, one line at a time, as it executes. If you take the time to learn how to use the debugger, you can use it with your program, and see for yourself how each line executes, and why.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be clear if you simulate the call stack, such as for invoking of `message(3)`:

```
message(3)         -> print out "This is a recursive function" and call message(2)
  |-message(2)     -> print out "This is a recursive function" and call message(1)
    |-message(1)   -> print out "This is a recursive function" and call message(0)
      |-message(0) -> print out "message returning with 0 in times" and return to message(1)
    |-message(1)   -> print out "message returning with 1 in times" and return to message(2)
  |-message(2)     -> print out "message returning with 2 in times" and return to message(3)
message(3)         -> print out "message returning with 3 in times" and return
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when time is decreased to 0, the recursion will return from the newest called one(time = 0) to the oldest called one(time = 5).
In each recursion return, the if clause is executed over, but the message function is not over, it will continue to execute the code 
    `cout << "message returning with " << times << " in times << endl;`.